# Call dblink from a trigger function

Tags: postgresql, trigger, functions, plpgsql, dblink

I have an environment where I have to move data from one database to another once a day. I Try to solve this by calling 'dblink' from a triggered function.

**The following statement I can execute from commandline:**

```
SELECT fieldA, fieldB, fielbC
INTO temp_table
FROM dblink('dbname=dbname port=5432 host=a.b.c.d user=user password=pw', 
            E'SELECT fieldA, fieldB, fieldC FROM data_table') 
     AS temp_table(fieldA integer, fieldB integer, fieldC integer);
```

But when trying to embed this into a pgsql procedure it won't work.

**I'm trying this by using the execute command:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION archive() RETURNS trigger AS $$
DECLARE
BEGIN

    execute 
    '
      SELECT fieldA, fieldB, fielbC
      INTO temp_table
      FROM dblink(''dbname=dbname port=5432 host=a.b.c.d user=user password=pw'', 
                  E''SELECT fieldA, fieldB, fieldC FROM data_table'') 
          AS temp_table(fieldA integer, fieldB integer, fieldC integer);
    ';

    return new;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I get an error telling me that `EXECUTE of SELECT ... INTO` is not implemented and I could use `EXECUTE ... INTO` or `EXECUTE CREATE TABLE ... AS`

Does anybody has some experience with this? I'm struggling for hours now :-(

Comment: @dezso - Thx that did the trick :-)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter now it _is_ an answer, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have nothing dynamically built in your query, you don't have to use `EXECUTE` at all.

Inside the function body, you can simply do an `INSERT` if `temp_table` already exists:

```
INSERT INTO temp_table (fielda, fieldb, fielbc)
SELECT a, b, c 
  FROM dblink('dbname=dbname port=5432 host=a.b.c.d user=user password=pw', 
              E'SELECT fielda, fieldb, fieldc FROM data_table')
       AS t(a, b, c);
```

If the table is not there yet, you can replace the `INSERT` line with

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE AS
...
```

Note that in your present approach (`SELECT ... INTO temp_table`) the table that is being created is *not* a temporary table, and on the next run the trigger will run into an error saying the table already exists.

Comment: Thx again now it's running smooth and fine :-)